# Files "File Manager" is not working. Icons are not visible

Tags: software-installation, update-manager

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04. I am not able to open the File Manager using the graphical UI. When trying to open it with `nautilus` or `sudo nautilus`, I am getting a segmentation fault.

Although I can open with nautilus admin:/// I cannot access any directory except home and I'm getting a `segmentation fault (core dumped)` error message. The desktop is not displaying any folder.

[image]

Icons like minimize, maximize and close are not visible.

[image: desktop icon are not visible]

Comment: Seems like GNOME is borked right off the bat. A reinstall should probably work.

Comment: This command "sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons" worked for me. i can open file manager with GUI. but icons are still not displaying.

Comment: This command "sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons" worked for me. i can open file manager with GUI. but icons are still not displaying.

Comment: this issue is not normal ... you no doubt ran something as root ( sudo ) to cause this